# Is there a way to run my JS code just in a named frame (instead of all frames) through Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, frame, greasemonkey

Let's say I have a frame based web page and it looks like this:

```
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|             |           header                                        |
|             +---------------------------------------------------------+
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |           main                                          |
| menu        |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             |                                                         |
|             +---------------------------------------------------------+
|             |           footer                                        |
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, there is a frame named `main`. When the user click the menu itesm in the `menu` frame, any pages (any URLs) can be loaded in the `main` frame. Now what I want is to run a piece of code just in the page that was load in the `main` frame. As I described, the pages that will be load in the `main` frame do not have a URL pattern so I can't specify a pattern in the `greasemonkey` script. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I would give the 'main' frame an `onload` event listener, so when a new page is loaded in it, a function gets called.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear.  If you mean an old fashioned (and obsolete in HTML5) frameset like:

```
<frameset ...>
    <frame name="header" src="header.htm"           ></frame>
    <frame name="menu"   src="menu.htm"             ></frame>
    <frame name="main"   src="ANY_DOMAIN/page.htm"  ></frame>
    <frame name="footer" src="footer.htm"           ></frame>
</frameset>
```

, then you have to set your Greasemonkey script to fire on all the possible pages that may be opened in the "main" frame.

Here's one way to do it:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Fire on any page, but only when it is the frame named "main"
// @include  *
// ==/UserScript==

//-- Run in (i)framed page only, not in parent page.
if (window.top != window.self) {
    if (window.name == "main") {

        // PLACE YOUR DESIRED CODE HERE.
    }
}
```

---

**Important:**

1. Use `@include *` only as a last resort.  Tune your `@include`, `@exclude`, and `@match` statements as much as possible to only run on the pages that you expect to be loaded in the frame named "main".
2. If these frames are all ***same domain*** then you have more options.  You can just run om the frameset page and inject code into the frame as needed.  Open a new question for that.
3. Tested with version 4.01 DOCTYPEs, in Firefox. Other browsers and HTML5 may be different or impossible.